# React Animation on state change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

On state change, the elements switch position based on the current array. I want to add an animation that shows the transition of swapping happening is there an easy way to do that.

```
   const bubbleSort = async () => {
      let arr = test;
      for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(let j=0;j<arr.length-1-i;j++){
          setActiveIndex([j,j+1]);

           if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
              let temp = arr[j];
              arr[j] = arr[j+1];
              arr[j+1] = temp;

           }
           await sleep(1000);

           setTest([...arr]);
        }
        setSortedIndex(test.length-1-i);
      }
```

Comment: I think you can do something with componentDidUpdate with the last and current state to rerender the page with "oldArr" and "newArr" and then set specific selectors that animate in/out. but I didn't test it my self.

Comment: Please post your solution if the above suggestion works

Comment: Are you looking something like this?https://images.app.goo.gl/29tJLLGHw7L4nTqu5

Comment: hi @Alex yes I am looking for something like that but with a swapping animation

Comment: Hi @MatanSanbira I am not exactly sure what do to here can you post something if you can reproduce the solution thanks

Comment: @Shubham, It's a swapping one, columns are wapping base on bubble sort method, it's a gif animation.otherwise what do you mean by swapping animation? could you please give us an example?

Comment: something like this https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a optional parameter to setState() that is a callback function , which executes on state change, you can execute desired actions there.

```js
this.setState({
     currentMonth: +this.state.currentMonth + 1
    }, () => {
     //This is the call back function, perform the desired actions here.
    })
}
```

Comment: not what I am looking for the transition animation need to happen before the state change

Comment: The componentWillUpdate() is a chance for us to handle configuration changes and prepare for the next render. If we want to access the old props or state, we can call this.props or this.state. We can then compare them to the new values and make changes/calculations as required.

Comment: I need animation before during state change once it is fired to the final value

Comment: If you are having other component where you are passing values as props use componentWillReceiveProps() else componentWillUpdate() works fine there you have access to both old and new props and state respectively you can add animation according to that. https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1